# Is there a Hidden MS Graph API Trick to Convert Excel to PDF with Ultimate Control?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've experimented with both the MS Graph SDK and the REST Endpoint for file conversion, following the documentation available here: [MS Graph API Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content-format?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). The documentation is well-structured and provides clear instructions.

The API accepts a `fileId` as a path parameter and a `format` as a query parameter. When specifying `format` as 'pdf,' it successfully returns a PDF version of the requested file.

However, I've encountered specific challenges when attempting to convert Excel files:

1. **Selective Sheet Conversion**: I aim to convert a specific sheet from the Excel file rather than all sheets. Unfortunately, removing unwanted sheets is not a viable solution, as it may disrupt references and result in a faulty final PDF.
2. **Page Size and Orientation**: The downloaded PDFs are strictly in A4 size. In cases where the Excel sheet contains numerous columns, the content wraps onto additional pages, making it challenging to read and understand. It would greatly benefit if there were options to customize the page size and orientation to better suit the content.

My question is whether there's a method within the MS Graph API that addresses these requirements for Excel sheet to PDF conversion.

Answer (score 0):

When converting a file to pdf, the Graph API is using [OneDrive API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content_format?view=odsp-graph-online) under the hood and you can't set a page orientation or size with the OneDrive's native converter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using power apps, and then display the excel data in a table space, and then use PDF formulas to screenshot the control and make it into PDF. In this way, you can control attributes such as paper type and margin size.

[image]